# How to read from a database, and write to a file asynchronously / non blocking way in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, io

I'm trying to modify a serial program that reads from a database, and writes results to a file, this is done in a blocking way and I think we can get performance boost of there is a memory buffer and have the file being written in the "background" asynchronously

I can think of the "job interview" solution, using Threads, shared resource, syncronized blocks etc... but I'm sure there is a better way (is there a nice little "delayed write" library out there that will do it for me?)

Does any of the java.util.concurrent package offer any help? java.nio? or perhaps JMS/ActiveMQ?

What about PipedOutputStream / PipedInputStream as a basis for my buffer?

How do I implement a delayed / background / buffered / non-blocking / asynchronous file writter in Java?

Comment: see original SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408055/how-to-read-from-a-database-and-write-to-a-file-asynchronously-non-blocking-w/10408583#10408583

Comment: What kind of time period? There are solutions to your problem, but if you want a "performance boost," first you should tell us what kind of performance you get as a baseline.

Comment: Thanks, will post some benchmarks here tomorrow, right now the suggestions I got and will try are: increased featch size from the DB, and increased BufferdOutputStream for the file writing, doing the delayed file writing should help a little, but I start to get convinced it won't make a huge difference

Comment: @BlackJack is correct, you need to figure out where your performance bottleneck is before trying to optimize it.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with both of you, but due to time constraints I had to do both in parallel, will take some time to get production stats, and in the meantime, trying to guess-optimize seems like better than waiting for the results. so anything I do that will not likely make things worse, is good in my view, isn't that so?

Comment: @Eran Medan:  Not really.  If you make multiple changes while you're waiting for production stats, and you get a slight improvement, which of the multiple changes had the biggest impact?  Experimenting with one change at a time, and measuring the results, gives better results.

Comment: Are you using Java 7?  It has Asynchronous I/O built into the new File System APIs

Comment: No but I will now!, does it have a specific package name I should focus on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while, but perhaps [this article on JSR 203](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/04/java-7-new-io-features-asynchronous-operations-multicasting-random-access-with-jsr-203-nio-2/) may offer some guidance. An example of what you may be after is given as:

```
AsynchronousFileChannel channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Paths.get("Path to file"));
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(capacity);

Future result = channel.write(buffer, 100); // Write capacity bytes to the file starting at position 100

boolean done = result.isDone(); //Indicate if the result is already terminated
// Alternatively...
int bytesRead = result.get(); // You can also wait for completion
```

Of course, before going down this route you should consider that you are not indulging in [premature optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#.22Levels.22_of_optimization). Make sure you have proof that an asynchronous operation will actually benefit your application.